# What is the difference between Object.create(BaseObject) and util.inherits(MyObject, BaseObject)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

What is the difference between this two solution to set the prototype?

```
MyObject.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);

MyObject.prototype = util.inherits(MyObject, EventEmitter);
```

**UPDATE**

Yeah, I see it in multiple projects where they set (restore) the prototype constructor to the actual object constructor like this:

```
MyObject.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
MyObject.prototype.constructor = MyObject;
```

What is the reason behind "restoring" the constructor? I use the quotation marks because this action seems much more like an override to me, since `MyObject.prototype` was the `EventEmitter` then the constructor of the prototype should be the constuctor of the `EventEmitter`. What is the advantage of restoring the prototype constructor? What real life problems does this solve?

Secondly what is the advantage of having the base constructor in a super_ property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`util.inherits` uses `Object.create` internally to assign prototype from superclass. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L726-L734) of inherits method, you'll notice it does few other things besides assigning prototype:

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {     
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

1. Restores the `constructor` reference on the prototype object. so that

   `MyObject.prototype.constructor === MyObject //true`

   This is to achieve classical OO inheritance in javascript. Without it you would create a child class whose constructor would point to it's parent class. If you are creating a module and if someone is trying to access the constructor of your class, they would incorrectly access parentClass constructor:

   ```
   MyObject.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
   MyObject.prototype.constructor === MyObject ; //false
   (new MyObject).constructor === MyObject; //false
   ```
2. Saves a reference to the superConstructor through `super_` property for convenience:

   `MyStream.super_ === EventEmitter; //true`

   Since the super constructor has been replaced as mentioned in previous point, if you ever need to access the super constructor, you could do it by using this property. For example, you can see inheritance chain of `fs.ReadStream`:

   ```
   var ReadStream = require('fs').ReadStream;
   ReadStream.super_.super_.super_ // ReadStream<-Readable<-Stream<-EventEmitter
   ```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply, I have updated my question to ask a few more things